# Размеры бегунка ScrollBar

Tags: winforms, c#

Доброго времени суток!

Возникла такая проблема - не могу нигде найти никаких подсказок и никакой документации.
Каким образом можно узнать ширину и высоту бегунка в ScrollBar. Как его прокрутить вниз до конца програмно на C#?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Уточните, WPF или WindowsForms

Comment: WindowsForms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Размеры, связанные с полосой прокрутки, можно узнать в `System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation`, а конкретно, в `HorizontalScrollBarThumbWidth` и в `VerticalScrollBarThumbHeight`. И кроме того, функция Windows API `GetSystemMetrics` с параметрами `SM_CXHTHUMB` и `SM_CYVTHUMB` дает те же значения.

По прокрутке. Если это `ScrollableControl` и у него выставлено свойство `AutoScroll` в `true`, то изменение `HorizontalScroll.Value` и `VerticalScroll.Value` должно вызывать прокрутку. Плюс еще остается возможность послать `SendMessage` c `WM_VSCROLL`.

Comment: подробнрее чем я ожидал) Плюсую)